# NHibernate one to many with LazyLoad off result in n+1 query

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, lazy-loading

i am trying to **turn off** lazyloading for **one-to-many** mapping in NHibernate. I have the follow mapping in my entity mapping class. An entity has many addresses, and what I was looking for is one query that basically join the base table to the Addresses table and return me all the result in one request. Instead I see a series of sql query submitted to database for each record in the base table.

```
HasMany(m => m.Addresses).Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Join();
```

i need a way to turn off lazyloading completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that would be anough:

`HasMany(m => m.Addresses).Not.LazyLoad();`

To get the data with select you should explicitly use "Fetch":

```
session.QueryOver<Item>()
   .Fetch(item => item.Addresses).Eager
   .Take(1000)
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
   .List();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest to read this blog post by Ayende: **[NHibernate is lazy, just live with it](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)**.

Using ORM and trying to avoid laziness... won't work. In case of addresses you will lose paging for example.

> *(while fetching them via join, what happens? If there will be entity with 10
>   addresses, and you will ask for first 10 records... you will get just
>   one. And it could be worse if you will ask for 11...)*

But what you can use, is the power of NHibernate: [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

```
HasMany(m => m.Address)
 ...
.Fetch.Select()
.BatchSize(25)
```

Now, if you will need 25 records, there will be 2 SELECTs. First for entity, second for all the related Addresses. That's improvement, while all the advantages of ORM remain.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you load the base entity with a HQL, Linq or plain SQL query. Those queries ignore the "join" fetch settings in the mapping. You have to either explicitly fetch the Adresses in the query or use Get/Criteria/QueryOver.

Reference documentation: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-custom